# Using express-fileupload how do i preserve file extension in temp files?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) and i need to preserve files in a temporary folder until compiling is done. My files can come in multiple different extensions, and i need them to be preserved.

I saw on their GitHub page that it's possible to preserve the extension, but I'm unable to get it to work. I might be misunderstanding the documentation, but it should be pretty straightforward.

This is my current options, i gave preserveExtension a larger number to allow longer extensions.

```
{
    tempFileDir: "tmp",
    useTempFiles: true,
    preserveExtension: 12,
    safeFileNames: true,
}
```

Example with image result, even with above options it still saves the files without the extension.

[image]

Comment: before doing the work/compiling, make a job id / unique hash which is then a folder name, then use the .mv method to move the files there, then after *compiling is done*, delete them

Comment: This is not related to my question.

Comment: Ok, short answer, you cant define the filename for tmp files, conflicts could/would occur

Comment: What is the point of the preserveExtension option in their documentation then? I'm not trying to define the filenames, just to preserve the extension in the tmp folder.

Comment: see docs for safeFileNames

Comment: It says in their documentation that safeFileNames is required for preserveExtension.


"Preserves filename extension when using safeFileNames option. If set to true, will default to an extension length of 3. If set to Number, this will be the max allowable extension length."

Answer (score 0):

If you meant, you want to save a file to `tmp` folder by `express-fileupload` with the extension it might be this this:

```js
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  ...

  const imageType = req.files["wallpaper2.jpg"].mimetype.replace('image/', '.')
  const imagePath = req.files["wallpaper2.jpg"].tempFilePath + imageType
  fs.renameSync(req.files["wallpaper2.jpg"].tempFilePath, imagePath)

  ...
})
```

Hopefully this could solve your problem :D

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2023, it doesn't look like the extension is preserved when using the `tempFilePath` option, as shown in the [express fileupload code](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/blob/master/lib/utilities.js#L34-L37):

```
const getTempFilename = (prefix = TEMP_PREFIX) => {
  tempCounter = tempCounter >= TEMP_COUNTER_MAX ? 1 : tempCounter + 1;
  return `${prefix}-${tempCounter}-${Date.now()}`;
};
```

Fortunately, you can work around this limitation by

1. getting the extension from the file object's "name"
2. renaming the temporary file to use the extension

For example...

```
const tmp_input_file_ext = req.files.file.name.slice((req.files.file.name.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
const tmp_input_file = req.files.file.tempFilePath;
const tmp_input_file_path_with_ext = tmp_input_file + "." + tmp_input_file_ext;  // will add a dot if there is no extension
req.files.file.mv(tmp_input_file_path_with_ext);
```